# The OpenMDAO ShelveRecorder saves the iterations in a weird order: 1st iteration, 3rd, 2nd, 5th, 4th, 6th

Tags: openmdao

I have just began using OpenMDAO 1.0 alpha, and I've noticed this behaviour when importing the shelve data recorded. So no question here, just a comment to see if I'm doing something wrong or not.

Cheers!

update: although the dictionary includes an 'order' entry with the right order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the recorder saves cases based on a string, which gets hashed by shelve we had to use the order attribute... its admittedly not a perfect solution.

But its really a side effect of being able to attach recorders to lower level parts of a model (not just drivers), like solvers and sub-solvers so you could get more detailed information about convergence and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Justin. And thanks for all the great work, I'm very enthusiastic about the alpha already! I can't complain about it, it was a minor comment for the team. And its very helpful as it is indeed.